# How to start and end an app based on time and days in the week selected by user?

Tags: android

Iam using Alarm manager to start the application and end the application. But I have a doubt how to use it based on day because the user can select day or days of the week. Please help with some example.
 public synchronized void startAppOnScheduleTime(final int time)
    {
      //create new calendar instance for your start time
       final Calendar startTime= Calendar.getInstance();

```
 //set the time to USER SPECIFIED start time
   startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time / 100);
   startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time % 100);
   startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1); // Add 1 second of additional delay

   /*System.out.println(" time set is  "+startTime.getTime().toString());

   System.out.println(" time set is  "+Long.toString(startTime.getTimeInMillis()));
   Date date = new Date(startTime.getTimeInMillis());
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
   String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);*/

   if (startTime.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() <= 0)
   {
       // Time has already past, schedule for next day
       startTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
   }
   try
   {
         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

         //create a pending intent to be called at startTime
          Intent myIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartApplicationReceiver.class);
         PendingIntent startPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         //schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, startPI);
    }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }

}

public synchronized void EndAppOnScheduleTime(final int time)
{
  //create new calendar instance for your start time
   final Calendar endTime= Calendar.getInstance();

 //set the time to USER SPECIFIED start time
   endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time / 100);
   endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time % 100);
   endTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1); // Add 1 second of additional delay

   if (endTime.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() <= 0)
   {
       // Time has already past, schedule for next day
       endTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
   }
   try
   {
           AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

           //create a pending intent to be called at endTime
           PendingIntent endPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EndApplicationReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

           //schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day
           am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, endTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, endPI);

   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     ex.printStackTrace();  
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GregorianCalendar

```
 Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
//set the current time and date for this calendar
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,    IntentBroadcastedReceiver.class);
PendingIntent PI = PendingIntent.getService(Activity1.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, PI);
```

Comment: Iam giving the user the ui to select days and based on those days which user has selcted i want to start the app